# Sequelize connect to multiple mssql databases

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I'm moving my node code from MySQL to mssql (sql-server), by using sequelize.
my code looks like this:

```
export const DbConnection1 = new Sequelize(config.CONNECTION.database1,
    config.CONNECTION.user,
    config.CONNECTION.password,
    {
        port: config.SEQUELIZE_CONNECTION.port,
        host: config.SEQUELIZE_CONNECTION.host,
        dialect: "mssql",
        pool: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
    }
);

export const DbConnection2 = new Sequelize(config.CONNECTION.database2,
    config.CONNECTION.user,
    config.CONNECTION.password,
    {
        port: config.SEQUELIZE_CONNECTION.port,
        host: config.SEQUELIZE_CONNECTION.host,
        dialect: "mssql",
        pool: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
    }
);

DbConnection1.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected sequelize DB1')
    })
    .catch((e: any) => {
        console.log(e)
    })

DbConnection2.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected sequelize DB2')
    })
    .catch((e: any) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
```

if I run this only one connection is connected, the first one fails on:

> ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Connection lost - read
> ECONNRESET

by removing one of them it is ok.

**NOTE:** this is the same code I had for MySQL that worked, just changed the `dialect: "mssql"`

what am I doing wrong? does sequelize support multiple connections for sql-server like for MySQL?

Comment: Well, that's what `pool` does. It opens up to `max` amount of connections. Did you specificially want two different connection pools to the same database?

Comment: I need two different connections for **two** different databases.